# Angular dropdown menu empty

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

So I have an Angular 9 app using Bootstrap 4.  I am trying to have a toolbar that contains a couple of dropdown menus.  The issue is that the items in the menus aren't showing when I click a menu button.

This is what it looks like in chrome with developer tools having clicked on the "Projects" menu button:

[image]

This the contents of my app.component.html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
  <span>Welcome</span>    
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="menu" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Standups
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="standups/reports">View Standup Reports</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="standups/create">Log a New Standup</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="menu" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Projects
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="projects/list">View List of Projects</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="projects/create">Create a new Project</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- end toolbar -->

<div class="content" role="main">

  <h1>Standup Logs</h1>

  <!-- Displays page content -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <svg id="clouds" alt="Gray Clouds Background" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2611.084" height="485.677" viewBox="0 0 2611.084 485.677">
    <path id="Path_39" data-name="Path 39" d="M2379.709,863.793c10-93-77-171-168-149-52-114-225-105-264,15-75,3-140,59-152,133-30,2.83-66.725,9.829-93.5,26.25-26.771-16.421-63.5-23.42-93.5-26.25-12-74-77-130-152-133-39-120-212-129-264-15-54.084-13.075-106.753,9.173-138.488,48.9-31.734-39.726-84.4-61.974-138.487-48.9-52-114-225-105-264,15a162.027,162.027,0,0,0-103.147,43.044c-30.633-45.365-87.1-72.091-145.206-58.044-52-114-225-105-264,15-75,3-140,59-152,133-53,5-127,23-130,83-2,42,35,72,70,86,49,20,106,18,157,5a165.625,165.625,0,0,0,120,0c47,94,178,113,251,33,61.112,8.015,113.854-5.72,150.492-29.764a165.62,165.62,0,0,0,110.861-3.236c47,94,178,113,251,33,31.385,4.116,60.563,2.495,86.487-3.311,25.924,5.806,55.1,7.427,86.488,3.311,73,80,204,61,251-33a165.625,165.625,0,0,0,120,0c51,13,108,15,157-5a147.188,147.188,0,0,0,33.5-18.694,147.217,147.217,0,0,0,33.5,18.694c49,20,106,18,157,5a165.625,165.625,0,0,0,120,0c47,94,178,113,251,33C2446.709,1093.793,2554.709,922.793,2379.709,863.793Z" transform="translate(142.69 -634.312)" fill="#eee"/>
  </svg>    
</div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

I made sure to also install popper (as is included in the scripts in the .html file).  This is what the "styles" and "scripts" in my angular.json looks like:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

I really don't understand why this is an issue.  Any ideas?

> Added:

It might help to know that I first added these dropdown menus before having installed bootstrap into the project.  Before bootstrap, they actually worked.  Adding the bootstrap did something.  Here is my styles.css content...maybe it has something to do with that?

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css');

:host {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }

  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  span {
    margin: 8px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  .spacer {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1976d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  .toolbar img {
    margin: 0 16px;
  }

  .toolbar #twitter-logo {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 16px;
  }

  .toolbar #twitter-logo:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .content {
    display: flex;
    margin: 82px auto 32px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    max-width: 960px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  svg.material-icons {
    height: 24px;
    width: auto;
  }

  svg.material-icons:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

  .card svg.material-icons path {
    fill: #888;
  }

  .card-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }

  .card {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 8px 16px;
    padding: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    line-height: 24px;
  }

  .card-container .card:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .card.card-small {
    height: 16px;
    width: 168px;
  }

  .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card) {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card):hover {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  }

  .card-container .card:not(.highlight-card):hover .material-icons path {
    fill: rgb(105, 103, 103);
  }

  .card.highlight-card {
    background-color: #1976d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 30%;
    position: relative;
  }

  .card.card.highlight-card span {
    margin-left: 60px;
  }

  svg#rocket {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: -24px;
  }

  svg#rocket-smoke {
    height: calc(100vh - 95px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 180px;
    z-index: -10;
  }

  a,
  a:visited,
  a:hover {
    color: #1976d2;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  a:hover {
    color: #125699;
  }

  .terminal {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 600px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(15, 15, 16);
  }

  .terminal::before {
    content: "\2022 \2022 \2022";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 4px;
    background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    color: #c2c3c4;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-indent: 4px;
  }

  .terminal pre {
    font-family: SFMono-Regular,Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,monospace;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .circle-link {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    transition: 1s ease-out;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  .circle-link:hover {
    transform: translateY(-0.25rem);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  footer {
    margin-top: 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
  }

  footer a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .github-star-badge {
    color: #24292e;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(27,31,35,.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,#fafbfc,#eff3f6 90%);
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol;
  }

  .github-star-badge:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,#f0f3f6,#e6ebf1 90%);
    border-color: rgba(27,31,35,.35);
    background-position: -.5em;
  }

  .github-star-badge .material-icons {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin-right: 4px;
  }

  svg#clouds {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -160px;
    left: -230px;
    z-index: -10;
    width: 1920px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.dropdown .btn {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-item a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-item a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-item {
  display: block;
}

.nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: darkblue;
}


  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .card-container > *:not(.circle-link) ,
    .terminal {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .card:not(.highlight-card) {
      height: 16px;
      margin: 8px 0;
    }

    .card.highlight-card span {
      margin-left: 72px;
    }

    svg#rocket-smoke {
      right: 120px;
      transform: rotate(-5deg);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
    svg#rocket-smoke {
      display: none;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
```

Comment: As a start, you can remove the head and body tags from your app component because angular loads the app.component.html inside of the documents body tag. You can also remove the script and style references from the app.component.html because they will be imported into your document from the angular.json configuration.

Comment: @Andy, creating  a demo on https://stackblitz.com/ will help to replicate issue and save sometime

Comment: @ShashankVivek - thanks, I'd never used stackblitz before. But for some reason it won't load for me (even though all I did was paste in the app.component.html, styles.css, index.html, and styles & scripts from angular.json).  I'll add some additional details to my question that will hopefully help.

Comment: @AshleyKurkowski - OK, I thought so...just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.  I did actually move that stuff into the index.html head and body tags there (didn't realized in the first place that this is where those are...I'm relatively new to Angular).  Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Andy: I have created a demo code structure with Angular 10 and Bootstrap 5. I think version should not be an issue. Can you give it a try : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxljww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts . Make sure to fork it